# Padronizar formatação de código Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Tenho um código gerado de forma automática conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria formatar de forma automática para que ficasse no formato:

```
public int Id {get; set;}
```

Obs: Esse código foi gerado automaticamente pelo Visual Studio projeto de modelação - Diagrama de classe
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: **`Ctrl`** + **`K`**, **`D`**

Comment: Não funcionou @jbueno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vai em: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> Wrapping -> (marque):

- Leave block on single line
- Leave Statements and member declaration on the same line

[image: Visual Studio Configuration]

Isso funciona em condições normais.

Comment: Já estava com essa configuração @bigown não funcionou. Investigando percebi que o template utilizado para gerar o código vem do arquivo `ClassTemplate.t4` na pasta `...\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\ARCHITECTURE TOOLS\EXTENSIBILITY\Templates\Text` Vou tentar aprender como modificar para ficar de acordo com o desejado.

Comment: Será que seu VS não está *bugado*?

Comment: Talvez, vou verificar esses `Templates` que são utilizados para gerar esses códigos automáticos. Tenho também `Resharper` e `Productivity Power Tools` não sei se pode ter algum conflito/bug.

Comment: Tenho a impressão que o `Resharper` 'tomou as rédeas' do `VS`. Quando seleciono o código e utilizo a opção `Format Selection` do `Resharper` o código fica padronizado como eu queira. De qualquer forma vou `Templates` para que o código seja gerado como eu quero.

Comment: @rubStackOverflow isso é importante, outras ferramentas impedem o funcionamento normal do VS, ainda que existam configurações para deixá-lo fazer isso. De qualquer forma o ReSharper permite configurar isso também. Talvez o problema não possa ser reproduzido, pelo menos não na forma apresentada na pergunta.